# libidn.so.11 error on starting an app

Tags: shared-library

I'm trying to run a Total English digital book, an app I need for my work. Upon running I get this message:

error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The file is installed on my system (Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit)

Answer (score 2):

If the application is a 32-bit version and not 64-bit, you have to install the 32-bit library version too.

Use the following command line (i.e. via gnome-terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install libidn11:i386
```