# GoPro Player on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I recently updated to 22.04 and I just realized that the GoPro player isn't working. I get this error:`/usr/lib/GoProVRPlayer/GoProVRPlayer: error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I tried to reinstall it following the link below:

[How can I view VR (virtual reality) 3D Video on a standard 2D screen in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882961/how-can-i-view-vr-virtual-reality-3d-video-on-a-standard-2d-screen-in-ubuntu/882962#882962)

However, I keep getting this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libidn.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tired this: `sudo apt-get install libidn11:i386` following this [libidn.so.11 error on starting an app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507384/libidn-so-11-error-on-starting-an-app). But didn't help.

Also tried this: https://linux-packages.com/ubuntu-jammy-jellyfish/package/libidn-dev but didn't help.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing it manually from previos version of ubuntu.
I installed it from this:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/i386/libidn11/download

It is a version from ubuntu 20.04. The lib itself only depends on libc so it should run just fine.

```
ldd /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7fae000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7d22000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7fb0000)
```

I had this problem with another application that also required this older libidn (among other older libs) and with this manually installed package from older ubuntu it just runs OK.

**PLEASE NOTE: DO NOT ADD THE WHOLE REPOZITORY FROM OLDER UBUNTU TO YOUR NEW UBUNTU VERSION AS IT WILL MOST LIKELY CAUSE PROBLEMS. JUST INSTALL THE 1 SPECIFIC PACKAGE FROM THE LINK I PROVIDED**

Another option is to build the library manually.